# panic: Register called twice for swag: swagger (Facing problem related to swagger in Golang)

Tags: go, swagger

I am facing issue in running my server after generating swagger using package swaggo/swag in Golang. It shows me error that Register is called twice.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
    panic: Register called twice for swag: swagger

    goroutine 1 [running]:
    github.com/swaggo/swag.Register({0x11af5ce, 0x7}, {0x1566dc0, 0x24fac20})
    /home/mind/go/pkg/mod/github.com/swaggo/swag@v1.8.6/swagger.go:36 +0x169
    services/payment-api/docs.init.0()
    /home/mind/go/src/services/payment-api/docs/docs.go:341 +0x2f
    exit status 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the imports you must have some repeated import